# How to order the list of questions by the number of views?

Tags: support

There is a list of questions [sorted by the number of votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). Is there a list of questions sorted by the number of views?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.
[There is a view](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq) that shows questions that are, in some way, prominent, and which consider the number of views as parameter; the questions are not sorted by the number of views, though.